# Cakephp use Set to filter results from a query

Tags: cakephp

The `Set::extract` is a very powerful function to filter out data retrieved from find method.
However, as far as I know, the results are not nested. I mean, if I have an array like

```
data = 
Array (
 0 => array(
   'User'   => Array (...),
   'Profile => Array (...)
   )
 1 => array(
   'User'   => Array (...),
   'Profile => Array (...)
   )
)
```

and I would extract all User with, let's say, `User.type =1`, I would do:

```
$filtered Set::extract('/User[type=1',$data).

$filtered = Array(
0 => Array (
     'User' => Array()
)
)
```

and the other array, Profile, is not shown. Is it possible to get all the data when filtering with extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse back the array path with /../ inside the first parameter.

Try

```
$filtered = Set::extract('/User[type=1]/..',$data);
```

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::extract

It says it's basic XPath 2.0 syntax and one of the examples uses it.

Comment: Great! Can you point to me where the doc explains that '..' ?

Comment: Wow really this is the best answer.

Comment: Why don't you just set conditions in the find or the pagination settings?